# You have no respect

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's say someone has made me very angry, so I say: "**You're rude. You have no respect. You're just a big idiot.**"

Is it natural to say "You have no respect" without adding more to it? Can it stand alone to mean "you're showing no respect"?

Comment: In context, the implication is that it's to you that no respect is being shown. But to be specific, you need to add **for me**. Whether you want to be insulting by calling the person an idiot is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

"You have no respect" is perfectly idiomatic. You *can* elaborate and say, for example, "you have no respect *for others*", but it is common to leave it there.

*Respect* is often spoken of as a *quality* that people possess, or not. Saying someone has "no respect" is not that different from saying they have "no patience" or "no common sense" - it's an insult, it doesn't have to be detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need for additing anything. In other words, if you say

> "Don't say that to me! You are so disrespectful!"

nothing should be specified out of context. In this example, it is obvious that the listener is being disrespectful [is showing disrespectful behavior] to the speaker in some way, so is it in yours.
Yes, you can say "have/show no respect" both of which are commonly used.